# Is Subversion better at cherry-picking then git (or any DAG VCS)?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, dvcs, directed-acyclic-graphs

I just read http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2013/09/07/no-cherry-picking.html and seems that `svn:mergeinfo` can track info about single commit merge which happen at cherry-picking.

That avoid merge conflict when you merge back your feature-branch with cherry-picked bug-fixes to original branch (where you made bug-fixes before).

Here funny ASCII art (which people like at SO):

```
      o--o--o--o--o    feature
     ^      ^      \
    /      /        v
-o--o--o--X--o---o---Y--o-->  dev
```

Here `X` - only single changeset (essential/blocker fix that we move from `dev` to `feature` branch).

I try and found that `Git` have conflicts in `Y` merge if you have made changes at lines which effected by fix `X` already. While `SVN` just skip that changeset from merge.

**UPDATE** That leads DAG VCS users to use `bisect` and аштв common ancestor from bisect and branches for fix propagation. So you can make clean history.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [read up on `rerere`](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html), which is short for "reuse recorded resolution". Git can remember how you resolved conflicts in the past and reuse those resolutions later, but you have to enable the feature.

`git config rerere.enabled true` will enable this feature in your repository (or use `--global` if you want to enable it by default on this machine for this user).

Comment: I dislike `rerere` as if I make a mistake on a merge resolution, it is difficult to get it right because it thinks it knows what I want it to do.

Comment: You can use `rerere forget [path]` and `rerere clear` to work around cached resolutions when necessary.

Comment: @Chris Wow! Something new to know. +1